# Socket program only works locally

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, networking, tcp

I have a client connecting to a server and sending a large message. The socket program works as expected if I run both client and server on the same machine but when I run the client inside another computer the server only partially receives the message.

The code is pretty simple,

Server:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.243");
    Socket Server = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    Server.Bind(new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 6666));
    Server.Listen(1);

    Socket client = Server.Accept();

    int bytesRead = 0;
    byte[] lengthHeader = new byte[4];
    client.Receive(lengthHeader);
    // Length header is the length of the message the server will send
    int prefix = BitConverter.ToInt32(lengthHeader, 0);

    Console.WriteLine("prefix is: " + prefix);
    // Make new buffer based off prefix, which is the length of the message
    byte[] recvBuffer = new byte[prefix];

    // Receive while there are bytes to be read
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Read: " + bytesRead);
        bytesRead = client.Receive(recvBuffer);
    } while (client.Available > 0);

    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBuffer));
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(recvBuffer).Length);
}
```

Client program

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{

    delimiter = "&$#*(dubsyw&^fe&vdbsry(#ueundosi[Dnrh(e*y*EL$&#*(hduu(]$%@^&udnsj*&dhuh*";
    IPAddress ipAddr = IPAddress.Parse("192.168.1.243");
    Socket TcpClient = new Socket(ipAddr.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
    TcpClient.Connect(new IPEndPoint(ipAddr, 6666));
    StringBuilder encoded = new StringBuilder();
    string[] dirs = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Windows/INF");
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles("C:/Windows/INF");

    foreach (string dir in dirs)
    {
        encoded.Append(dir + delimiter);
    }

    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        encoded.Append(file + delimiter);
    }

     string toSend = encoded.ToString();
     Console.WriteLine("Length: " + toSend.Length);

     byte[] lengthHeader = new byte[4];
     byte[] sendBuffer = new byte[Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend).Length];
     sendBuffer = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(toSend);
     lengthHeader = BitConverter.GetBytes(sendBuffer.Length);

     TcpClient.Send(lengthHeader);
     TcpClient.Send(sendBuffer);

     Thread.Sleep(50000);
}
```

When I run this program on two seperate machines the number of bytes received is less than the number of bytes sent? Why does this happen? I'm using a do while loop just like the docs does?

Comment: _"the number of bytes received is less than the number of bytes sent? Why does this happen?"_ -- because that's exactly how TCP is documented to work. There are numerous questions and answers already on Stack Overflow discussing this aspect of TCP, including the two marked duplicates.

Comment: @PeterDuniho my question is different from the two duplicates you linked. The answers talk about using an application protocol and how Socket.Receive() doesn't read  all the bytes in one go. If you look at my code you'll see I'm already using a header-prefix protocol as described here https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/04/sample-code-length-prefix-message.html

You'll also see I'm using Socket.Receive() in a while loop as used in the documentation. Kindly reopen the question and remove your downvote...

Comment: You still have the same exact problem as in the other questions, because you do broken things like assuming the entire bytes for the length value will be received in one call, and that the `Available` property being `0` indicates reaching the end of the data. Neither of these are true. You just need to spend more time looking at how to _correctly_ deal with framing in TCP, which is what the marked duplicates (and many, many others on Stack Overflow already deal with).

Answer (score 0):

TCP may break the user data into pieces and the data may arrive in parts. So in your receiver side of code, you always collect the received data into a byte buffer until the desired size is received.

All of this is part of the communication Protocol your application will follow. Generally, make the message over the wire as:

```
public class NetworkMessage
{
    public Header Header {get; set;}
    public Body Body {get; set;}
    public Trailer Trailer {get; set;} // optional
}

public class Header
{
    public int Size {get; set;}
    public string SenderId {get; set;}
    public int MessageType {get; set;}
}

public class Body
{
    public byte[] Buffer {get; set;}
}
```

Now, you know that a fresh read will always deliver Header followed by Body.
So when you read some bytes of the Network, Marshal it to Type NetworkMessage class.
Try and see if the Header object is readable and you can identify the Size property.

Say the Size value is 500. So then you got to collect 500 bytes from the network and then cast them as Network packet.

Alternative approach is to agree between Server & Client - that a fixed bytes will be sent (ex: 1024). So on Receiver side you collect 1024 bytes. Cast the First few (SizeOf(Header) to header, identify how many bytes you need to process from this 1024. If Message Size is less than 1024, you need to slice the buffer and hold on to second part until next 1024 bytes arrive. I hope you get the gist.

Comment: "Alternative approach is to agree between Server & Client - that a fixed bytes will be sent (ex: 1024)."
I am sending the first 4 bytes as the message length prefix so my program knows how long the message is.

Comment: I found the answer, I was overwriting the contents already in the buffer because I didn't specify an offset in Socket.Receive()